# Why does rails not recognize `Accept: application/json` in the request header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xmlhttprequest, http-accept-header

I have some frontend javascript that makes an asynchronous http request to my backend rails server. On the frontend I am *not* using XHR (I use `axios`, although that's not entirely relevant to the question).

In the request, I set the following to tell the server I'm sending JSON and to make sure I get JSON back:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
};
```

In my backend Rails controller if inspect the request I can verify the `Accept` header:

```
> request.headers
"HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"application/json, text/plain, */*"
```

However ActionPack/Rails still does not respect that and defaults to the `format` being `:html`

```
> request.format
=> #<Mime::Type:0x00007fe223919f80 @hash=-1773238723920954657, @string="text/html", @symbol=:html, @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"]>
```

Why is that?

I know I can append `.json` to my request URL to "force" it to specify that format, but is that the only option? I can append it easily but it seems like an implementation specific to Rails and not really the "right" approach.

Additionally, the [source code for the `request.format` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb#L59) explicitly sets `:json` as the format on XHR requests - does rails only respect XHR requests at the moment?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing is correct, but sending the Axios/Fetch API requests from browser will show "CORS" error from the browser end(you can see it in your browser dev tools console). You can know more about it from [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

To resolve this, You'll need to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Header to the requests you receive on your web server. You can do it manually by adding this header in `application_controller.rb` or Simply use a gem like `rack-cors`. I'll show you how to do using `rack-cors` gem:

- Add `gem 'rack-cors'` in your `Gemfile`
- Run the command `bundle i`
- In your `config/application.rb` file, add the following lines:

  ```
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
    end
  end
  ```
- Now restart your rails server
- You can also see above instructions and more details [here](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors#installation)

Now make the API call again without forcing `.json` at the end of the URL and it should work.

Comment: I've found a good recent article about CORS - https://dev.to/miguelmota/understanding-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-2i3e

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But my request is not cross-origin. My front end and backend are under the same domain.

Comment: Can you update the code of your axios request? Do you see any errors in console? Any thing specific in `rails server` logs?

Comment: I've just tested in a test app - react + rails(one app), I used Fetch API and it's working fine.